# vuex getter with html

Tags: html, vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex implementation which has getter getScore() and I would like return html code to template, but template escapes me the result html to raw text.

vuex code looks like:

```
  getters: {
    getScore(state) {
        return state.score > 10 ? "<b class=\"green\">" + state.score + "</b>" : "<b class=\"red\">" + state.score + "</b>";
    }
  },
```

result is not html but raw text e.g. <b class=“red”>5</b>

How to return html which will be inserted as html to the template? Thanks for any help.

Comment: instead of sending html why not set a class condionally if score > 10?

Comment: It is only an example not real use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) directive to get it to render as HTML.